# How does the Drag and Drop feature to create layout works in Android Studio? How to code is generated by Drag and Drop?

Tags: android, android-layout

I just wanted to know how does the Drag and Drop feature to create layout does its works in Android Studio, means how does it creates the views and tags according to the drag and drop action?

Comment: Do you want to know the internal working of the IDE or do you need an explanation of how to use the design editor?

Comment: @cutiko, Yes I want to know the internal working of the IDE.

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly, current redaction is misleading. Also, give your question some more context, I'm not sure if something like that is allowed by the SO books.